# How Do I Add More Claims to the Identity Token in ADFS Using ADAL Libraries?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, adfs

This may be a simple question but I'm pretty new to ADFS, but I'm using ADAL Libraries for ADFS and I'm wondering if I can get claims to show up in the short lived identity token as opposed to the accessToken.

I have this code:

```
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);
var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceURI, clientID, new Uri(clientReturnURI), new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto));
```

And the `authResult` gives me two tokens: the `accessToken` and the `IdToken` and all the claims I've set in ADFS shows up in in the `accessToken`. But I wanted the `accessToken` to only include an identifier like a GUID (to keep it small), and keep information about the user (name, email, etc.) in an IdToken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ADFS 2016 then you can look at [Customize claims to be emitted in id_token when using OpenID Connect or OAuth with AD FS 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/custom-id-tokens-in-ad-fs) as ADFS 2016 has the capability to customize the id_token for OpenID connect scenarios.  You can see these additional claims as part of id_token using the same code to access claims.